# Identify which checkbox was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of checkboxes on my page. Code for one of them:

```
<div>
            <label for="ViewAsWebpage">
                {{#if this.ViewAsWebpage}}
                    <input type="hidden" id="ViewAsWebpage" name="ViewAsWebpage" value="true"/> 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox" checked /> 
                {{else}}
                    <input type="hidden" id="ViewAsWebpage" name="ViewAsWebpage" value="false"/> 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox" /> 
                {{/if}}
                <span>View as Webpage</span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

I am trying to set the value to true/false based on user clicks and then want to post that value when the form is submitted as follows:

```
$('input.enable-checkbox').click(function (e) {

                    if ($('input.enable-checkbox').parent().attr("for") == "ViewAsWebpage") {
                        var checked = $('#ViewAsWebpage').is(":checked");
                        $('#ViewAsWebpage').attr("value", checked);

                    }
```

Is there a better way to set the checkbox value to True/False by identifying the checkbox that was clicked on the page (there are multiple)?

Comment: Why don't you change `$('#ViewAsWebpage').attr("value", checked);` to `$('#ViewAsWebpage').val(checked);`?

Comment: @David: It means the same thing.

Comment: @dotNetNewbie Yes, sorry, didn't notice your if and else statements, you should post the rendered markup instead of serverside codes.

Comment: @dotNetNewbie So why make longer what you can make shorter and clearer?

Comment: The issue that I am having has nothing to do with making it shorter and clearer. I can do the code clean up once the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input.enable-checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('label').val(this.checked);   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should give IDs to your checkboxes themselves. then:

```
$("#idCheckbox1").change(function(){
   if($("#idCheckbox1").attr('checked')){
       $("#ViewAsWebPage").val("true")
   }
}

$("#idCheckbox2").change(function(){
   if($("#idCheckbox2").attr('checked')){
       $("#ViewAsWebPage").val("false")
   }
}
```