# Checkbox serialization issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a webpage with multiple checkboxes (code for one of them below):

```
<div>
        <label for="ViewAsWebpage">
            {{#if this.ViewAsWebpage}}
                <input type="hidden" id="ViewAsWebpage" name="ViewAsWebpage" value="true"/> 
                <input id="chkViewAsWebpage" type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox" checked /> 
            {{else}}
                <input type="hidden" id="ViewAsWebpage" name="ViewAsWebpage" value="false"/> 
                <input id="chkViewAsWebpage" type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox" /> 
            {{/if}}
            <span>View as Webpage</span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

I have an event handler that handles the change event (for all checkboxes):

```
changeCheckboxValue: function(e) {
            var target = this.$(e.target);
            var id = this.$(e.target).siblings().attr('id');

            $(id).val(target.is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false');
```

The above event works great and sets the true/false value.

However, when I serialize the form (to POST the form values on submit)- these updated values are not reflected. Can someone pls let me know what I am missing?

Comment: How's this different from your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643858/identify-which-checkbox-was-clicked?

Comment: I was struggling with a way to handle the checbox and finally got the code running where it correctly sets the true/false value. The issue now is serialization

Comment: what do you mean by 'serialize the form'?

Comment: serialize the form to POST the values on submit

Comment: `$('#myForm').submit();` should work just fine, does it not?

Comment: @JimmyBoh: That works but the value that is POSTed is not correct (eg. if the checkbox was checked and the user unchecked it... it still goes out as checked instead of unchecked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was  the missing #.

Fixed, by changing :

```
$(id).val(target.is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false');
```

to

```
$('#' + id).val(target.is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the checked property:

```
$(id).prop("checked", true);
```

or

```
$(id).prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you are using the same `id` for all the `hidden` fields.

Let's review this code:

```
changeCheckboxValue: function(e) {
    var target = this.$(e.target);    // get the checkbox that is clicked
    var id = this.$(e.target).siblings().attr('id');  // get checkbox's siblings' id
                                             // so id == 'ViewAsWebpage'
    $(id).val(target.is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false');  // HERE!!
              // $(id) returns all the hiddens that have id == 'ViewAsWebpage'
```

So the value of all the hiddens change altogether for several times. They will be all 'true' or 'false' eventually.

I think you should select the hidden fields like this.

```
changeCheckboxValue: function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    var hidden = target.prev();

    hidden.val(target.is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false');
```